# What does the slash in polymer nomenclature, e.g. Acrylates/ Beheneth-25 Methacrylate Copolymer, mean?

Tags: nomenclature, polymers

I was given a task to find SDS-Sheets for polymers/microplastic particles in cosmetics and I am confused, since there are often two chemicals divided by "/", e.g. Acrylates/ Beheneth-25 Methacrylate Copolymer. So would it be correct to look for the SDS-sheets for the both of them separately? Is it just the mixture of the two? Maybe someone can provide me with some information of how I am supposed to read these kinds of names.

Answer (score 4):

*Acrylates/Beheneth-25 Methacrylate Copolymer* is an [INCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Nomenclature_of_Cosmetic_Ingredients) name for a [copolymer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copolymer)

> … formed from the ester of 2-methylpropenoic acid and docosanol, ethoxylated, 25 mol EO (average molar ratio) and one or more monomers of acrylic acid, methacrylic acid or one of their simple esters

(Source: [cosmetics.specialchem.com](https://cosmetics.specialchem.com/inci/acrylates-beheneth25-methacrylate-copolymer#Formulations))

Also known by the trademark *Aculyn™ 28*.
Dow Chemical provides cumulative [MSDS datasheet (pdf)](http://msdssearch.dow.com/PublishedLiteratureDOWCOM/dh_0880/0901b803808806df.pdf#page=3) for the entire Aculyn family, so I assume you can use it for your copolymer as well.